# AEM list children from path

Tags: aem

I am relatively new to AEM and on version 6.1. I am trying to list out children based on an authorable filepath, but can't seem to figure it out. Previously, I had something like

```
<sly data-sly-list.child="${currentPage.getParent.listChildren}" data-sly-unwrap>...</sly>
```

and it worked as intended. Now, I need to make it more generic, but

```
<sly data-sly-list.child="${properties.filePath.listChildren}" data-sly-unwrap>...</sly>
```

doesn't iterate through. I think I need to use the "resource" object, but not sure how. Can I use it directly in my Sightly call? Or do I have to create/edit current java files? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

I would advice you to use a `Sling Model` to return a list of children to your HTL template. The following code is a simple version of such a model based on the little information you gave:

```
import org.apache.sling.api.resource.Resource;
import org.apache.sling.api.resource.ResourceResolver;
import org.apache.sling.models.annotations.Optional;
import org.apache.sling.models.annotations.Model;
import org.apache.sling.models.annotations.injectorspecific.ValueMapValue;
import org.apache.sling.models.annotations.injectorspecific.OSGiService;

import java.util.Collections;

@Model(adaptable = Resource.class)
class MyModel {

    @ValueMapValue
    @Optional
    private String filePath;

    @OSGiService
    private ResourceResolver resourceResolver;

    public Iterator<Resource> getChildren() {
        if (this.filePath == null || this.filePath.isEmpty()) { // Use StringUtils.isBlank() if you can.
            return Collections.emptyIterator();
        }

        final Resource resource = this.resourceResolver.getResource(this.filePath);

        if (resource == null) {
            return Collections.emptyIterator();
        }

        return resource.listChildren();
    }
}
```

And your HTL template might look like this:

```
<sly data-sly-use.model="my.package.MyModel">
    <sly data-sly-list.child="${model.children}" data-sly-unwrap>...</sly>
</sly>
```

Remarks:

1. The `filePath` should be `@Optional` because there are edge cases when your component will not be configured yet but the model is instantiated. For example: Editor adds the component to the page but has not yet opened and saved the edit dialog. The component will be rendered, the model instantiated but `filePath` is going to be `null`.
2. Obviously, your HTL template might look a little bit different.

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't be able to do it straight forward in HTL since `properties.filePath` returns a `String`, and you do not have a `listChildren` method in the String class.

Earlier `currentPage.getParent` returns a `Page` which inturn returns a `Iterator<Page>` upon calling the `listChildren` method.

Since HTL doesn't allow you to call methods with parameters at the moment, you may need to use the Java Use API or the JS Use API to handle this scenario.

To learn more about HTL and Use API refer [this doc](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/htl/docs/use-api.html).